# Mysqldump creating a partial backup

Tags: database, mysql

I need to test a MySQL database in another server. But database is too big to export and import. Besides I only need some part of database to test.

Let's assume that database has 20 tables and I need to get last 10000 records from each table. How can I create a `mysqldump` for this situation ?

(Related: [How to use mysqldump for a portion of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658284/how-to-use-mysqldump-for-a-portion-of-a-table))

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution. This dump can be done if all tables has `id` field. By ordering results by id, you can get results.

```
mysqldump --user=backup_user -p databasename 
   --where="1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000" | gzip > /targetfolder/file.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysqldump with **--where** condition.

For example:-

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [dbname] {--opt} --where="true limit 10000" > dump.sql
```

Comment: Well this dumps first 10000 records. Is it possible to get last 10000 records, if number of records is bigger then 10000.