# dump query on multiple table

Tags: mysql, dump

Im trying to have a sql output file from a query between three tables. 
Below is my code:

```
mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=localhost dbname --where="SELECT v.ITEM_ID , v.CODE ,\
s.SENSOR , d.DESTINATIONCODE \
FROM  V_TABLE v, S_TABLE s ,D_TABLE d \
WHERE s.ITEM_ID = v.ITEM_ID \
AND s.CREATIONDATETIME <  '2014-2-16 00:00:00'\
AND v.DESTINATION_ID=d.ID" > /var/www/dumps/output_15_12_2017.sql
```

this give me an error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `COMMANDSPOOL` WHERE SELECT v.ITEM_ID , v.CODE ,s.SENSOR , d.DESTINATIONCODE FROM  V_TABLE v, S_TABLE s ,D_TABLE d  WHERE s.ITEM_ID = v.ITEM_ID AND s.CREATIONDATETIME <  '2014-2-16 00:00:00' AND v.DESTINATION_ID=d.ID': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT v.ITEM_ID , v.CODE ,s.SENSOR , d.DESTINATIONCODE FROM  V_TABLE' at line 1 (1064         )
```

maybe it is an error in using \

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mysqldump for a portion of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658284/how-to-use-mysqldump-for-a-portion-of-a-table)

Comment: `--where` can only provide the where clause, not a complete select. use `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'output_14_12_2017.sql'` for that.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, i wrote:
`--where="SELECT v.ITEM_ID , v.CODE ...` or you mean in 
`> /var/www/dumps/output_15_12_2017.sql` ?

Comment: look at the answer from @jeremy-jones, it's explained in there :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a query like that you could send it into the `mysql` client, (not the `mysqldump` utility) and then redirect that output to the file instead:

```
echo "SELECT v.ITEM_ID , v.CODE ,\
s.SENSOR , d.DESTINATIONCODE \
FROM  V_TABLE v, S_TABLE s ,D_TABLE d \
WHERE s.ITEM_ID = v.ITEM_ID \
AND s.CREATIONDATETIME <  '2014-2-16 00:00:00'\
AND v.DESTINATION_ID=d.ID\
" | mysql --user=user --password=password --host=localhost dbname > /var/www/dumps/output_15_12_2017.sql
```

If you're going this route then the `--batch` and `--table` options can be useful.

Comment: this worked for me. First I log into mysql
`mysql -u name -p dbname`
and then run the query
`select ..... into outfile '....sql';`